# Reading a data from a file and writing it to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, text-files, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Node{
    char *name;
    int time;
    int sec; 
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Node *next;
};
int main(){
    FILE *file;
    int index;
    struct Node *data=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *tmp=data,*tmp2=data;
    int enter;

    file=fopen("data.txt","r");

    if(file==NULL){
        printf("File was not opened!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while(!feof(file)){
        tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        fscanf(file,"%d",&index);
        fscanf(file,"%d",&tmp->time);
        fscanf(file,"%d",&tmp->sec);
        fscanf(file,"%d",&tmp->x);
        fscanf(file,"%d",&tmp->y);
        fscanf(file,"%s",tmp->name);
        fscanf(file,"%'\0",&enter);
        tmp->next=NULL;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    fclose(file);
    while(tmp2 != NULL){
        printf("file:%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n",tmp2->timestamp,tmp2->sec,tmp2->pointx,tmp2->pointy,tmp2->name);
        tmp2=tmp2->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Need some help with reading data from a file and write them to the linked list and after that print the linked list to the secreen.But it stops working immedately after I start the program.In the file data is like that:

- 1    28000   41  29  50  bbb
- 2    29000   91  19  60  ccc
- 3    30000   23  77  92  ddd
- 4    30000   37  62  65  eee
- 5    31000   14  45  48  fff

(there are tabs between them)

I read many questions but their answers didn't help me.I think I'm missing a point somewhere but I couldn't see the problem.Is it about reading a data directly to the linked list or something else? Thanks for help.
//I'm looking at my code againt thanks for help**(edited)

Comment: This `"%'\0"` is exactly the same as this `"%'"`, what is it supposed to do according to you? If you read the documentation, what do you think it will do?

Comment: "..  it gives an error message .." Please **never** let us guess what specific error you get.

Comment: BTW, you are still learning, and *you should read a lot* and experiment. Be aware that you need several days of full-time work on this homework.

Comment: There are compilation errors in your code. For example: the code is trying to access pointx and pointy in the structure which does not exists. I agree with other people to take this problem as a learning opportunity and debug it more. Running it through gdb will be definitely fun..

Answer (score 3):

The `name` field is a pointer, but you never allocate it. So

```
    fscanf(file,"%s",tmp->name);
```

is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You really should be [very scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). Take a few hours to read Lattner's blog: [*what every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Perhaps you might use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if on a POSIX system to read a line, or else use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html).

BTW, when I compile your code with all warnings & debug info (with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)) I'm getting many errors and warnings. You should improve your code till you get no warnings. Then you should use debugger (`gdb`) to find many other bugs. You'll be able the run your buggy program step by step and query some variables. You should draw on a chalkboard (or on a paper) what you believe is the model and shape of the memory (including heap) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running your program. You'll find several bugs. Read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) and [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Also, `#include <stdlib.h>`  is required when using [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

Please read the documentation of every function that you are using, notably for [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Notice that you forgot to handle failure of `malloc`; and I also recommend using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) in failure cases. So at least replace `tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  with

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
if (!tmp) { perror("malloc Node"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>PS. I hope you don't expect us to do your homework. Your program is extremely buggy, but you'll learn a lot by finding *by yourself* these bugs. Asking someone else is counterproductive.</sup>