# When Should I Free a Double Pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I am having trouble understanding when to free a pointer to a pointer. For arrays, I understand that something like:

```
char **mat = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);

for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    mat[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
```

Would require

1. Freeing each *ith* member of the mat variable, followed by a final free call to its root (the mat**). This intuitively make sense because each malloc gets a free.

However, when I do something like so:

```
char *str = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
char **pstr = &str;

free(pstr);
```

I find this tells me I'm attempting to free an invalid pointer. My logic is if `pstr` is a pointer to a pointer to a malloc'd character array - freeing `pstr` should free `str`. Instead, I get an invalid pointer. What gives?

Comment: Spend several hours in reading more about C and [C memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management). You need to define and follow *conventions* about allocation & memory release

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer. You pass (a copy of) that very pointer to `free`. Not its address or anything else.

Comment: You don't free pointers (double or otherwise), you free objects by using pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> char *str = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
> char **pstr = &str;
>
> free(pstr); //WRONG
> ```

This is wrong. `pstr` is the address of some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) (so is likely to sit on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), not in the heap). It was not obtained by `malloc`, so `free`-ing it is forbidden ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), i.e. UB). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) of UB.

Pointers are *values*. You can only `free`  a pointer (actually the memory block it points to) which was previously obtained (indirectly perhaps) by `malloc` or `calloc` (and these can fail: you forgot to [handle failure of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449615/841108)).

Consider defining some [`Matrix` abstract data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30683866/841108).

Be aware that **conventions are *very* important when coding in C**. You need to define, document and follow your own conventions (regarding who is responsible of `free`-ing stuff and how that should be done - perhaps with [destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming))-like functions). So studying the source code of *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) should be inspirational.

Comment: "address of some automatic variable". This is what I needed to realize. I had too many pointer concepts moving around in my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The allocated memory is pointed by `*pstr` so you have to `free(*pstr)`.